# Monkey patching a PyCharm function

Tags: python, pycharm, monkeypatching

I use the embedded Python interpreter of a program from within PyCharm. When I click on the run icon, PyCharm simply runs my module as a script, which works as expected:

```
/third-party/Python/bin/python3 -m my_package.my_module
```

However, when I want to run the module in debug mode, PyCharm executes

```py
/third-party/Python/bin/python3 /home/zoltan/Programs/PyCharm/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --module --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 36223 --file my_package.my_module
```

which raises an exception.

#### Cause of the problem

Following the traceback, I found that the `_get_major_version` function causes the problem in `/home/zoltan/Programs/PyCharm/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/matplotlibtools.py`.
The problem is that `_get_major_version` assumes that the *matplotlib* external package is named as `matplotlib-MAJOR.MINOR.FIX`. However, the program that ships its own Python has a *matplotlib* package named as `matplotlib-0+unknown`.

#### A working solution

As I have permission to edit the `matplotlibtools` module, I modified it so that it handles the case when it receives `matplotlib-0+unknown` as input. This works properly but I would like a more elegant, non-intrusive solution.

#### An alternative

I thought of monkey patching. This is what I tried at the top of my module:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/zoltan/Programs/PyCharm/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/')
import matplotlibtools
old_fun = matplotlibtools._get_major_version
def new_fun(module):
    return 2
matplotlibtools._get_major_version = new_fun
```

However, it has no effect: when PyCharm calls this function, it calls the original function and not the patched version.

#### Question

Why is the original function called, and not the patched version? Is it related to how IPython works or something else?

Comment: It seems this is a question of Python, so you should tag it as python question, else you only the people interested of PyCharm editor may see your question and help you. [Use edit link to edit your question (tags are part of editing)]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, somehow I forgot about it.